# Google Apps Script - how to save ss as new file and have file on screen become the new file

Tags: google-apps-script

I know how to write script to make a copy of an active spreadsheet (with my script, the spreadsheet is actually open on my screen) and save the copy with a filename name I give it to the folder I specify.

This is nice, but the spreadsheet open on my screen remains the original. I would like to know how to write a script to do as I describe above and close the original and open the copy on my screen. That is, I want the script to act as Microsoft Word and many other programs act - when you're working on a file and then click "save as".

Thank you!!!

Answer (score 1):

The only way that you could open the newly created spreadsheet file, would be to have some kind of HTML user interface (Dialog, Sidebar, HTML App) that used something like `window.top.location.href = url` to open the new spreadsheet.  There is no way to open and close Google files from Apps Script server side code.